# Changing the BackColor of a Cell Does't work in Form's Constructor

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

My code seems pretty straight forward, I'm not sure what I'm missing...

I'm looping through each row in `dataGridView.Rows`, then looping through each cell and checking if its value is `"OK"` then I change the cell color to `Color.Red` and also write `"IF WAS TRUE"` in console.

I have that nice little `"IF WAS TRUE"` in console window just to prove to myself that the if statement is getting caught (it is). But my cell color remains unchanged `White`.

Any advice would be appreciated!

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static BindingList<Record> record_list = new BindingList<Record> { };
    public static DataGridViewCellStyle style = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        FillData();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(row.Cells[i].Value);
                if (row.Cells[i].Value as string == "OK")
                {
                    row.Cells[i].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("IF WAS TRUE");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    void FillData()
    {
        record_list.Add(new Record("Support-19", "TEST", 0, 0.0, "", 
            "LOC CODE2", 0.0, 0, 0, 0.0, ""));
        record_list.Add(new Record("Support-99", "ROBOTS", 0, 0.0, "",
            "OK", 0.0, 0, 0, 0.0, ""));
        record_list.Add(new Record("Support-27", "TEST2", 0, 0.0, "", 
            "LOC CODE1", 0.0, 0, 0, 0.0, ""));
        dataGridView.DataSource = record_list;
    }
}
```

```
public class Record
{
    public string Station { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int EvtActive { get; set; }
    public double EvtTime { get; set; }
    public string EvtTimeString { get; set; }
    public string LocCode { get; set; }
    public double LastLoop { get; set; }
    public int CompLvl { get; set; }
    public int RecordID { get; set; }
    public double ConnectTime { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    public Record(string a, string b, int c, double d, string e,
        string f, double g, int h, int i, double j, string k)
    {
        this.Station = a;
        this.UserName = b;
        this.EvtActive = c;
        this.EvtTime = d;
        this.EvtTimeString = e;
        this.LocCode = f;
        this.LastLoop = g;
        this.CompLvl = h;
        this.RecordID = i;
        this.ConnectTime = j;
        this.Notes = k;
    }
}
```

EDIT: This was marked as duplicate, but this seems different to me. In the other SO post, it looks like a cell is being sent to a function directly where as I am iterating over cells. I try to call the BackColor property in a similar manner and I get no results...

Comment: What type of cells are they? Are you getting an error?

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger Not sure how to answer that question, I don't know what "type" of cells they are. String? 

Also, no error. Just no color change, do I need to "refresh"?

Comment: @LarsTech Will do, thanks for the advice.
Code doesn't error out, but the colors do not change.

Comment: DataGridViews have all different types of columns. If these are textboxes, you'd be better changing the backcolor of the textbox, not the cell. If you share your code, we can help. Creation of DataGridView to be specific

Comment: Your code won't work since you are calling this in the form's constructor.  Move the loop to the OnLoad override.

Comment: I checked the posted code with a small change, I moved the for to Load event of Form and it worked properly.

Comment: By the way, when posting a code to reproduce the problem, include all required classes too. For example here you need to include `Record` class. I used a `Tupple<string, string, ...>` instead.

Comment: @RezaAghaei That's alarming, what should I do? Reinstall VS?

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger How do I tell if these are textboxes?

Comment: @LarsTech Could you explain what a "OnLoad override" is and how to use it?

Comment: @RezaAghaei What is a "Load" event? How do I use it?

Comment: @MrDysprosium I added an answer which describes the root cause of the problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The changes which you make on cells and rows of `DataGridView` in constructor (before form `Load` event) will not be persisted and they will be lost. It's not about just styles, it's about all changes on rows and cells.

In fact the columns and rows which you see after load are not those that you see in constructor.

The short answer (as said) is you should initialize styles in `Load` event of form. **But Why?**

**Why do changes which you make on cells and rows of `DataGridView` in constructor don't persist and they lost?**

The answer is because of `OnBindingContextChanged`of `DataGridView`.

When you show a `Form` sequence of tasks that shows a `Form` cause calling these methods: `CreateControl` → `OnBindingContextChanged`. Which cause `OnParentBindingContextChanged` of each child control be called and as a result, `OnBindingContextChanged` of all child controls will be called.

Now if you take a look at [`DataGridView.OnBindingContextChanged`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewMethods.cs,9e01f3da1b213244) you will see, a method named [`RefreshColumnsAndRows`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewMethods.cs,7ac7eaab1c161b0b) called which clears all rows and columns and add them again:

```
private void RefreshColumnsAndRows()
{
    this.Rows.ClearInternal(false /*recreateNewRow*/);
    RefreshColumns();
    RefreshRows(true /*scrollIntoView*/);
}
```

So the columns and rows which you see after load are not those that you see in constructor. They are new objects. So changes which you made on rows and columns in constructor will not be persisted.

**What's the correct way of dynamically changing styles?**

Although you can move your code to `Load` event of `Form` but a more suitable place to style rows and cells dynamically is using [`CellFormatting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx) event of `DtaGridView`

Answer (score 0):

Decorating the cells doesn't "stick" when you try to run your code in the form's constructor.  Move it to the form's OnLoad override instead:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
  base.OnLoad(e);

  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)
  {
    for (var i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(row.Cells[i].Value);
      if (row.Cells[i].Value as string == "OK")
      {
        row.Cells[i].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
        Console.WriteLine("IF WAS TRUE");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, that fixed it. Could you talk a little about "OnLoad"? VS seemed to know what I was trying to do the moment I typed OnLoad (it autocompleted the EventArgs and added the base.OnLoad(e) to it as well), this is something hard coded in Winforms?

Comment: @MrDysprosium It's equivalent to the form's load event.  If you type "override" on a free line, you should see a list of all possible overrides the form class provides.  A form shouldn't need to listen to its own events (load, paint, etc) since it can directly access the "OnABC" methods.