# Which override in Winforms will trigger when data is added to a grid's itemsource?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I currently use `Onload(EventArgs e)` to fire a function that will iterate over my data and change colors of cells based on value, but when I add data to the DataGridView's itemsource I'm not sure how to call this same function.

Is there an override to satisfy this case?

Example of what I currently use for `OnLoad`:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    PaintSquares();
}
```

Comment: You don't need to iterate between rows and cells, it's enough to use `CellFormatting` event of `DataGridView`.

Comment: I'll look into that, but in the mean time, is there an override for my current use case?

Comment: Btw, there is no `ItemSource` in WinForms, are you mixing with WPF :)

Comment: @IvanStoev I sure am, I just switched to Winforms from WPF, nice catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to iterate between rows and cells to format them, it's enough to use `CellFormatting` event of `DataGridView`:

```
void grid_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex < 0)
        return;

    if (string.Format("{0}", e.Value) == "OK")
    {
        e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

If for any reason you want to use some change events, [`ListChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist.listchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event of the data source is suitable event for detecting occurrence of a change. `BindingSource` and `BindingList<T>` (which you are using - based on your previous question) both have `ListChanged` event.

Also you can rely on `DataGridView` events like [`RowsAdded`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowsadded(v=vs.110).aspx), [`RowsRemoved`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowsremoved(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`CellValueChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Welp, you're definitely right. `CellFormatting` is what I wanted all along.
Thank you again!

Comment: Read the last paragraph in [answer to your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39497762/3110834) about styling cells: *What's the correct way of dynamically changing styles?* It seems the post answers your question.