# Unable to change the background color of DataGridView cells

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewrow, datagridviewcellstyle

I'm attempting to loop through the rows within a datagridview and change the colour of a single cell depending on its stored value.

I have tried the two methods below but neither work and no exceptions are thrown.

1:

```
row.Cells[8].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

2:

```
dgvProperties[row.Index, 8].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

3 (another attempt since writing this question, also does not work):

```
dgvProperties.Rows[row.Index].Cells[8].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is this WinForms or WebForms or something else?

Comment: Sorry, it's a .net windows forms application.

Comment: I guess you have the solution at this topic: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105718/datagridview-changing-cell-background-color)

Comment: maybe this is a helpful post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189376/how-to-change-row-color-in-datagridview9

Comment: [Changing the BackColor of a Cell Does't work in Form's Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39496272/3110834)

Comment: The problem has been described in above link. A good solution is using `CellFormatting` event.

Comment: You 100% correct. Thank you @Reza Aghaei… I removed my answer as your comment  _”A good solution is using `CellFormatting` event.”_ … is IHMO the best solution for this! @Paul Alexander … wire up this event… and the loop becomes unnecessary. Thank you, Reza for this valuable info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I guess this is what you are looking for..

```
for(int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            int val = Int32.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
            if (val < 5)
            {
               dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
```

Credits: [here](http://1bestcsharp.blogspot.com/2015/05/c-datagridview-row-color.html)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

> row.Cells[i].Style["background-color"] = "red";

if does not work anyway you get the row in wrong way

Comment: Visual studio flags up "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'DataGridViewCellStyle'"

Comment: if  dgvProperties is your datagridview: dgvProperties.Rows[index].Cells[index].Attributes.Add("style","background-color:red") maybe this would work

Comment: or: row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;

Answer (score 0):

Here is a VB.NET example of working code, however, it will be trivial to apply to your C# application:

```
Private Sub dgvResults_DataBindingComplete(
        ByVal sender As Object,
        ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs
        ) Handles dgvResults.DataBindingComplete

    Dim daysOpenThreshold As Integer = 10 'Some trivial value for this example.

    For Each r As DataGridViewRow In dgvResults.Rows

        If CInt(r.Cells(2).Value) >= daysOpenThreshold Then

            Dim style As New DataGridViewCellStyle
            style.BackColor = Color.Red
            style.ForeColor = Color.White

            r.DefaultCellStyle = style

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```