# Changing font to DataGridView row is not working in WinForms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have methods which manages datagridview object:

```
internal static void LoadChannelsInGrid(DataGridView dg, Label noDataLbl, string feedUrl)
{
    var response = RssManager.GetRss(feedUrl);
    if (response != null)
    {
        noDataLbl.Visible = false;
        dg.Visible = true;
        var items = response.OrderByDescending(s => s.PubDateUnix);
        dg.DataSource = items.ToArray();

        FontifyDataGrid(dg);
    }
    else
    {
        noDataLbl.Visible = true;
        dg.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

and

```
private static void FontifyDataGrid(DataGridView dg)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < dg.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        var item = dg.Rows[i].DataBoundItem as ChannelData;
        if (item == null)
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (!item.IsLoaded)
        {
            var actualFont = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 7.8f, FontStyle.Bold);
            dg.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.Font = actualFont;
        }
    }
}
```

and I call :

```
LoadChannelsInGrid(dataGridView1, noDataLbl, "https://....");
```

Seems that rows (which model item satisfy `IsLoaded` value) don't have bold style, still looks regular.

Why ?

Comment: In the RowPostPaint event, try something like: `if (!((dg.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem as ChannelData)?.IsLoaded)) { dg.Rows[e.ColumnIndex].DefaultCellStyle.Font = [newFont]; }`. You should have that font stored somewhere, so you don't need to `new` it each time. I doesn't seem you want to substitute it with something else when the condition changes.

Comment: The changes which you make on cells and rows of `DataGridView` in constructor (before form Load event) will not be persisted and they will be lost. It's not about just styles, it's about all changes on rows and cells. Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39497762/3110834) the case? Also as it's already mentioned by Jimi, in general you may want to consider using cell/row events like `CellFormatting`, `RowPrepaint`, ...

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you need the font to be bold when the IsLoaded property is true.

In that case you need to update your `if (!item.IsLoaded)` to `if (item.IsLoaded)`